# Linear fractional transformation of quadratic differentials on the Riemann sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

Suppose I have the following quadratic differential on the Riemann sphere with four punctures:

\begin{equation}
q = -\frac{9 t \left(216+t^3\right)}{\left(-27+t^3\right)^2} dt^2
\end{equation}

This has four zeroes, and four second-order poles (one for each of the punctures).

Now, since $q$ is on the sphere, we should be allowed to do an $SL\left(2, \mathbb{C}\right)$ reparameterisation, of the form $t \rightarrow \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. So, to test, choose $a=c=b=1$, and $d=2$. Then, using the quadratic differential transformation rule that if $q = f\left(z\right)dz^2 = g\left(w\right)dw^2$, then

\begin{equation}
f\left(z\right) = g\left(w\left(z\right)\right)\left(\frac{d w\left(z\right)}{dz}\right)^2 ,
\end{equation}

I find

\begin{equation}
q = -\frac{9 \left(1729+4324 z+3894 z^2+1516 z^3+217 z^4\right)}{(2+z)^2 \left(215+321 z+159 z^2+26 z^3\right)^2} dz^2 .
\end{equation}

This now has *five* second-order poles. But it should still be living on a sphere with four punctures, so it looks like it has picked up another pole. This confuses me; I had really hoped the number of poles would be invariant under such reparameterisations.

So, my question is:

- Is such an $SL\left(2,\mathbb{C}\right)$ transformation on a quadratic differential on a Riemann sphere with punctures actually legitimate? If not, why not?
- If the transformation *is* legitimate, what is the explanation for the extra pole in the quadratic differential after the transformation?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: For sure it is legitimate. You're only dealing with meromorphic sections of the second symmetric power of the cotangent bundle of the Riemann sphere. Pulling back preserves the order poles, it may only change their position. I think you're missing something in the calculations...

Comment: Why does the second form have five poles? I didn't calculate them but I see only 4 second-order poles. It is holomorphic at $\infty$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest! Of course you are correct -- I was incorrectly counting a pole at $\infty$. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question, as Alan Muniz points out, is that such $SL\left( 2, \mathbb{C} \right)$ transformations of the quadratic differentials *are* legitimate, and they *do* preserve the number of poles of the quadratic differential. The problem in the above is that I incorrectly counted five poles in $q\left(z\right)$, when in fact there are only four - since $q\left(z\right)$ is holomorphic at $\infty$.